# How to change WebSettings's setSavePassword as true in aosp source code Android 10?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-source, android-websettings

I need to know which class sets the value of `WebView`'s `setSavePassword()` to `true`.

I have checked the framework source code of WebSettings in the path:
`frameworks/base/core/java/android/webkit/WebSettings.java`

But I found only the **abstract** class method.

```java
/**
* Sets whether the WebView should save passwords. The default is {@code true}.
* @deprecated Saving passwords in WebView will not be supported in future versions.
*/
@Deprecated
public abstract void setSavePassword(boolean save);
```

Let me know which class the default value of the boolean changed to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the WebView source code:
Navigate to the WebView module in the AOSP source code. The WebView code is typically located in the frameworks/base/core/java/android/webkit directory.

Find the WebSettings class:
Look for the WebSettings class within the android.webkit package. The file might be named WebSettings.java.

Locate the setSavePassword method:
Search for the setSavePassword method within the WebSettings class. It should be a public method responsible for setting whether passwords should be saved.

Modify the method implementation:
Change the implementation of the setSavePassword method to set the value to true. The code might look like this:

```
public void setSavePassword(boolean enable) {
    mSavePassword = true;
}
```